# What are the alternatives to developing two DotNetNuke modules differing only in the back end business process?

Tags: c#, asp.net, module, dotnetnuke

In a custom system development the client wanted me to develop two separate modules. However these two modules are similar (in UI and nature of data displayed each is basically listing a set of records); they both differ only on the data queried, i.e. the criterion of data fetch is slightly different.

So I thought of developing a single module and allowing the DNN administrator to configure the module in a page with settings that depended on how she/he wanted data in the page.

1. However I am not sure that my thoughts are correct. Is this really possible? How should it map to the DNN architecture?
2. Is there another alternative you may suggest? I don't really wish to develop a whole module just for the purpose of a change in query. It won't help my client or me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible you can just set a property in the module settings on the preferred action the admin wants at that specific time.

Comment: Ok, let me draft it in this way: While developing the module,we can define the properties(i.e preferred action) which could be set by the DNN admin while configuring the module. And once configured in a page the module always behaves as its preferred action was set.             Am i right?. Any way thank you for the thought, and i should be trying the same.

Comment: Yeah each instance will be able to do either option they can simply pick which they need for that page

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the reports module that ships with DotNetNuke, it covers what you seem to require. Alternatively you could implement templating as a module setting, which would allow you to install 2 different instances of the module, or even just one and copy it (module settings are indpendant)

Comment: No,i haven't been through the reports module. Thanks for the tip let me check it & will get back. Apparently i should be learning more on implementing templating. Is it different from what Matt has mentioned above?

Comment: Yes - templating and module settings are different. Templating lets you separate the view from the underlying data. Generally a template-based system will allow you to swap out different templates so the data renders differently. Implementing module based settings simply allows an administrator to choose options about how your module should work/display (and it's up to you to act upon those settings in your module code).